# Finding multiple counts of phrase in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need something counts the number of times a certain phrase presents itself in a SINGLE cell.

Cell B5 contains the value "Test 123 Test 1234"

```
Sub count()
ival = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B5"), "Test")
MsgBox ival
End Function
```

This returns "0" because it's not an exact match.  I want something that counts the number of times "Test" is in the cell and properly returns 2 as the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Ubound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Split the string into zero based 1D array of substrings, then find the upperbound of that array using ubound

```
Sub count()
 Dim count As Integer
 count = UBound(Split(Range("B5"), "123"))
 MsgBox count
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 That's a nice way to do it. Note that it returns -1 for an empty cell. You could add a `WorksheetFunction.Max` to handle that. Or maybe it's more informative the way it is.